# Python AES256-CBC, decryption with Rust OpenSSL

Tags: python, rust, cryptography

I'm using this OpenSSL call to encrypt (symmetric) a file

```
key = secrets.token_bytes(32)
iv = secrets.token_bytes(16)

encrypted_file = file_path + ".enc"
subprocess.run(
    [
        "openssl", "enc", "-aes-256-cbc",
        "-K", key.hex(),
        "-iv", iv.hex(),
        "-in", file_path,
        "-out", encrypted_file,
    ]
)
```

and this Rust code to decrypt it.

```
let mut ctx = CipherCtx::new().expect("Can't build CipherCtx");
ctx.decrypt_init(Some(Cipher::aes_256_cbc()), Some(&key), Some(&iv)).unwrap();

let mut data = vec![];
archive.read_to_end(&mut data).expect("Can't read encrypted archive file");

let mut bytes = vec![];
ctx.cipher_update_vec(&data, &mut bytes).unwrap();
ctx.cipher_final_vec(&mut bytes).unwrap();

let mut decrypted_file = tempfile().expect("Can't create temporary file");
decrypted_file.write_all(&bytes).expect("Can't write decrypted archivce file to disk");
```

**It does work**. But I want to use the Python `cryptography` library to encrypt my file instead. So I replaced the block above with

```
with open(file_path, "rb") as raw_file, open(encrypted_file, "wb") as enc_file:
    encryptor = Cipher(algorithms.AES256(key), modes.CBC(iv)).encryptor()
    enc_file.write(encryptor.update(raw_file.read()))
    enc_file.write(encryptor.finalize())
```

which I think is asking the same thing (eas-256-cbc, same key/iv, but in bytes, not hex). But now I get this error at the `ctx.cipher_final_vec(&mut bytes)` line

```
ErrorStack([Error {
    code: 101077092,
    library: "digital envelope routines",
    function: "EVP_DecryptFinal_ex",
    reason: "bad decrypt",
   file: "../crypto/evp/evp_enc.c", line: 610
}])
```

Because I use OpenSSL 1.1.1# in Rust, I also tried using `cryptography v36.0.2` (statically linked to OpenSSL 1.1.1n) instead of the latest version (39.0.1 is statically linked to OpenSSL 3.0.8), but I get the exact same error.

What do I need to change for Rust to be able to decrypt my file?

Comment: The Python code does not pad automatically, while the Rust code requires PKCS#7 padding. You have to pad the plaintext in the Python code, see [here](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/padding/#module-cryptography.hazmat.primitives.padding).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained by @Topaco in comment above, `cryptography` does not automatically pad the data you're trying to encrypt, so you must do it yourself. This is as simple as

```
with open(file_path, "rb") as raw_file, open(encrypted_file, "wb") as enc_file:
    # !!! New code here !!!
    from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import padding
    padder = padding.PKCS7(algorithms.AES256.block_size).padder()
    padded_data = padder.update(raw_file.read())
    padded_data += padder.finalize()

    encryptor = ...
    enc_file.write(encryptor.update(padded_data))
    ...
```

This simply pads the file's bytes in order to reach the required block size (128 for AES256). Then you can encrypt like you normally would.

The padding is linked to the "mode". As written in the documentation for [CBC](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/symmetric-encryption/#cryptography.hazmat.primitives.ciphers.modes.CBC):

> CBC (Cipher Block Chaining) is a mode of operation for block ciphers. It is considered cryptographically strong. **Padding is required when using this mode.**